# Found a script i want to use but getting lots of errors when applying it

Tags: pine-script

Preface- i have no coding knowledge at all. Ive found a script on github that i want to use but when adding it to my pinescript editor im getting errors.

is it that it needs updating from version 3 to 4? Does anyone know how to update a script from version 3 to 4?

Wheres the best place to pay someone to work on this for me?

appreciate any advice guys thankyou.[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndEdP.jpg)

Comment: Where is the source of this code? Can you give us the link? It shouldn't be that difficult to convert it.

Comment: We maintain a list of Trusted Pine Programmers for Hire here, if you decide to go that way:
https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/#trusted-pine-programmers-for-hire

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to version 4 in the Pinescript editor, just click the button to convert to 4, but it won't solve the errors.